# Check cursor's value

Tags: android, cursor

I have cursor and i want to check cursor's value. For example,

```
 if (it is null)
 kayitlar[i]=""
 else
 kayitlar[i]=cursor's value.
```

How can i do that ? Thanks for help!

```
Cursor okunanlar = v3.GetAllRows();
okunanlar.moveToLast();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
kayitlar[i]=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("name"));
okunanlar.moveToPrevious();
}
```

I solve this problem with it;

```
if(!okunanlar.moveToPrevious())
{
    kayitlar[i]="";
    okunanlar.moveToPrevious();
}
else
{
    kayitlar[i]=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("name"));
    okunanlar.moveToPrevious();
}
```

But now i have new problem:

I have tab menu and 2 tabs. When I'm creating tab2 i get my values from db. Than i write new value to db from tab1 and i click again tab2 but i cant show new value in listview. How can i refresh my db ?
Note: Listview in tab2

Comment: I'm confused - if you know how to get values from the cursor what are you having an issue with? Why can you just get a value, check for null, and set accordingly?

Comment: I create listview and I want to get last 20 values from database. So if database hasn't 20 values i should check null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
Cursor okunanlar = v3.GetAllRows();
if(okunanlar == null)
    throw new IOException("null cursor");

int i = 0;
while(okunanlar.moveToNext()){
    kayitlar[i]=okunanlar.getString(okunanlar.getColumnIndex("name"));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somethig like this?. 0 is the column

```
 if(okunanlar.moveToFirst){
do{
  string x = c.getString(0);
if(x==null)
{x="";}

 kayitlar.add(x);
}while(okunanlar.moveToNext);
```

Comment: Don't use a do/while loop when a while loop will do just fine